# capybara: post, get methods not working when changing name of requests directory to features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, rspec, get, capybara

After upgrading to the latest version of Capybara, all of my visit methods stopped working so I followed a solution presented by some people which was to rename the requests spec directory to "features".  Now my visit methods are working again but any get or post method in a request spec causes this error:

```
undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007f9cce9adc20>
```

Here's the code that triggers the error:

```
describe "getting posts" do
    before { get(forum_posts_path) }
    it "should respond with a 200" do
        response.response_code.should == 200
    end
end
```

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't rename the **spec/requests** directory to **spec/features**: you have *both*:

- Tests that use the Capybara DSL (`visit` etc) and usually assert against `page` go in **spec/features**.
- Tests that use the rack-test DSL (`get` etc) and usually assert against `response` go in **spec/requests**

See this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14379154/567863) for details, specifically the external links there.